# How to call jquery validation from javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I ve placed a small validation in a javascript function . Now i need to call jquery validation from javascript function .. how can i call the jquery validation from javascript ???

Comment: Er, just call it like any other function?

Comment: can u give me with an example ..

Answer (score 1):

From the [jquery tutorial site](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

you can do:

```
$("input[type='text']").change( function() {
    // check input ($(this).val()) for validity here
});
```

if you want to validate text inputs

Comment: I am using Labelify and Validate plugins of JQuery. Error messages displayed for invalid data are Title field of text boxes. I want to use the custom messages? while not affecting the title message

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the [form](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form)() method of the validation plugin

```
var valid = $('form').validate().form()
```

Comment: function clickFunc() {for ( var i = 1; i <= divLength; i++) { var productGroupId = document.getElementById("productGroupId"+i+"").value;  if(productGroupId ==1){ document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Please select Product Group";
        return false;
                  }  }   // this s a function.  hw can i call jquery validation from this ..

Comment: and why call an additional jquery validation function if you already have your own validation?? The normal way would be to write a jquery validation validator (e.g. you function) and then invoke the validation of the entire form the jquery validation plugin.

Comment: actually i ve invoked a value 1 for the function so jquery wont validate t .. but for the remaininig column i ve jquery validation...